# UTF-8 Character Printing Error Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8, non-ascii-characters

I write codes that contain non-ASCII characters like this;

```
print "Öüç"
```

I know that Python's default encoding is ASCII. So I add this to my code.

```
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
```

When I launch my code, "Öüç" string appear like this;

```
├û├╝├ğ
```

What should I do?

Comment: without setting any utf encoding, my Pythin 2.7 and 3.1 seems to print your same string as is passed. What is your issue here?

Comment: I want to print my code as I write.

Comment: and it already does that? isn't? (if you remove utf-encoding from your code)

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri: I assume OP is using the 437 charset under Windows...

Comment: @SergeBallesta Looks like you were write (+1)

Answer (score 1):

That is only loosely related to Python. Even `#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-` is useless here: it is only meant to allow to use encoded unicode litterals in Python source.

It just allowed me to guess that your source was UTF-8 encoded, so `"Öüç"` is in fact the following string: `'\xc3\x96\xc3\xbc\xc3\xa7'`. And what you see is those characters in the code page 437.

I assume that you use a Windows system, and that the `chcp` command in a CMD windows would confirm you that the code page used is indeed 437.

What can be done? First you must select in the console a code page able to display the 3 characters, I would advise the 850 code page: `chcp 850` before starting Python

Then in Python, you decode the UTF-8 string into unicode and encode it in cp850:

```
print "Öüç".decode("utf8").encode('cp850')
```

Alternatively, you can use the windows 1252 code page which is close to Latin1: `chcp 1252` before starting Python and then:

```
print "Öüç".decode("utf8").encode('latin1')
```

Comment: Those .decode/.encode's worked, but do I have to put them to every code in my project?

Comment: For a start, you could use `unicode` literals, which allows you to write `print u'Öüç'.encode('cp850')`. In Python 3, you'd even write `print('Öüç')`, but you'd still have to make sure that the terminal uses the right codepage (or a Unicode encoding), and that Python uses the same.